# Failing to return any immutable data from collection.emptylist()

Tags: java

I am a novice in Java but I am trying to get to grips with the usages of collection.emptylist(). From my understanding, this should return non modifiable values.

I have included my code below:

```
package com.carfilter;

import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class DataFilterer {
    public static Collection<?> filterByCar(Reader source, String Car) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

And the second class:

```
public class CarFiltererExample {
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnEmptyCollection_WhenLogFileIsEmpty() throws IOException {
        String readLine = "";
                  try{
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(openFile("src/test/resources/empty"));
                     while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                         assertTrue("true",DataFilterer .filterByCar(openFile("src/test/resources/empty"), "Jaguar").contains(readLine));
                     }
                     br.close();
                  }catch(Exception e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }

    }

    private FileReader openFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new FileReader(new File(filename));
    }
}
```

And in the ...empty.file, i have the following

```
Jaguar, 1865, black
Porsche, 1999, blue
Aston Martin, 2000, red
```

What I am trying to do is to return value as true if collection contains the value of the readline buffer. Unfortunately collection is just returning empty [].

My question is it possible to achieve this without modifying the DataFilterer  class?

Comment: `emptyList` returns a list with no elements. How would you expect it to filter or keep any elements?

Comment: I'm curious: The first sentence of the javadoc for  [`Collections.emptyList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--) says *"Returns an empty list (immutable)."* Which part of that is confusing about the point that the list *is*, and *always will be*, **empty**? And since an empty list by definition doesn't contain anything, why would you believe that `filterByCar(...).contains(...)` would ever not be `false`? Or is it simply that you didn't *read* the javadoc?

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.emptyList()` returns a list with zero elements. This means that the code:

```
assertTrue("true",DataFilterer.filterByCar(file, "Jaguar").contains(readLine))
```

is in fact checking if an empty list contain `readLine`, which is always false.

Comment: Thanks, guess i got the wrong end of the stick with regards to the collections.emptylist

Comment: Answer is partially wrong. [`Collections.emptyList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--) does return an empty list, but that list *is immutable* (see javadoc), i.e. you cannot add values to it. So, it is both **empty and immutable**. Rest of answer is spot on, so up-vote anyway. :-)

Comment: If you want to make a list immutable, you can use `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)` for that.

Comment: Andreas - you're correct indeed. Let me fix the answer.